# Gimp - only has print to file

Tags: printing, snap, ubuntu-mate, gimp

When I try to print from Gimp, it only shows print to file.

It offers none of my printers.

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo snap refresh gimp --edge

sudo snap connect gimp:cups-control
```